Error in Android file flutter project in vs code
[flutter project error in Android folderenter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/tC2Onqqy.jpg)
I see the previous answer on stackover flow but I don't understand anything so, anybody know why this error show I'm download all flutter plug in vs code

VS code and Visual studio are different ide. If you really want to develop app for desktop also then only download Visual Studio but if you only want to develop for Android, ios and web. Just ignore it you are good to go.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Simply run this command :
flutter doctor -v

If you only want to develop mobile apps using Flutter, you can run
flutter config — no-enable-windows-desktop

to disable the desktop support for your Flutter projects. After that, when you run the flutter doctor command again, you will no longer see the warning.
